# Change website theme dynamically via buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-web-developer

I've been learning a bit of asp.net and I've been having issues with the whole dynamic theme change, I've been following a book that teaches how to do it via a drop down menu, but I wanted to challenge myself and do it with buttons.

My website has 2 themes and therefore, two buttons that represent each theme (orangefresh and greenfresh), this is my master page code behind:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class mpage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string selectedTheme = Page.Theme;
            HttpCookie webtheme = Request.Cookies.Get("webtheme");
            if (webtheme != null)
            {
                selectedTheme = webtheme.Value;
            }

        }
    }
    protected void orangefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie webtheme = new HttpCookie("webtheme");
        webtheme.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3);
        webtheme.Value = "orangefresh";
        Response.Cookies.Add(webtheme);
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
    }

    protected void greenfresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie webtheme = new HttpCookie("webtheme");
        webtheme.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3);
        webtheme.Value = "greenfresh";
        Response.Cookies.Add(webtheme);
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
    }
}
```

And this is my Base Page:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
HttpCookie webtheme = Request.Cookies.Get("webtheme");
if (webtheme != null)
{
    Page.Theme = webtheme.Value;
}
}
public BasePage()
{
    this.PreInit += new EventHandler(Page_PreInit);
}
}
```

Seeing as I have no experience with cookies, I decided to look at the code from the beginning, I tested out if the Click event was storing a value on the cookie, I created a Label on the website and gave it's .Text property the cookie's .Value, nothing happened. So I started to remove code to see what was stopping the event, and I found that this line...

```
 Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
```

... was responsible for it. Just for the sake of it, I removed that one line and tested my website again, still, no changes in the theme.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you set up the themes in the web.config?

Comment: I've put up <pages theme="orangefresh"></pages> on my web.config file, as that is the default theme, is there anything else I should have done?

Comment: Can you post the markup for the masterpage?

Comment: Take their example for the drop down and whatever code they are using to trigger the change in the drop down take that and use it for your respective buttons. It essentially should be the same idea since i believe they would both use an OnClick event.

Comment: Here is a pastebin with it: http://pastebin.com/FCZ3ySZQ

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with this. Have you tried applying the theme on the page level just to test it's being applied? `<%@ Page Theme="orangefresh" %>`

Comment: I tried this <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/mpage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="index" Page Theme="orangefresh"%>, but I get an error: 
Error parsing attribute 'page': Cannot create an object of type 'System.Web.UI.Page' from its string representation '' for the 'Page' property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I forgot to make the change so that the page I was testing in inherited BasePage... it was inheriting the default page.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18300/How-to-change-page-theme-in-asp-net-2-0-dynamicall

Comment: they are using a drop down list, so it doesn't really help me with this code, i'd like to see this working with cookies.

Answer (score 0):

**Everything Works fine ..**
problem may exist on your themes.Check them at page level(as Duane said!!). 
try this..

`<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/mpage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="index" Theme="orangefresh"%>`

Comment: I've tried both the themes and they work just fine... Theme="orangefresh" and Theme="greenfresh"